# OTC stocks and their foreign stock exchange equivalent

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, stock-markets, stock-exchanges

Do OTC stocks trade similarly to their foreign exchange equivalents?

I'm looking at a company that is not available for US investors on the ASX, but it has ticker on the OTCQX. My broker shows me historical data for this ticker, and it shows it never rose above $0.6 all the way back to 2002; whereas if I look at other charting sites, it shows historical price data similar to the ASX component.

I'm not sure who to believe. I would have thought that the OTC equivalent trades just like it would on its primary exchange, with the only difference in price being the currency used.

Do OTC stocks not trade at the same value as their foreign exchange component?

Edit: the company is ASX:DYL and OTCMKTS:DYLLF; charts:

- OTC: [DYLLF](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/DYLLF/overview) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4igAK.png))
- Fidelity: [DYLLF](https://digital.fidelity.com/prgw/digital/research/quote/dashboard/chart?symbol=DYLLF) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTTsK.png))
- Google: [DYL](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/DYL:ASX?window=MAX) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Ikm.png))
- Google: [DYLLF](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/DYLLF:OTCMKTS?window=MAX) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T60qx.png))

I'm just unsure why OTC/Fidelity show such low pricing for the OTC stock in years when the company is trading for much 4-5x on its primary exchange duirng that time; plus I'm not sure why Google/StockTwits/Tradingview/SeekingAlpha all show similar price history for the OTC stock but OTC/Fidelity don't. OTC says that DYLLF has been a member of OTCQX since 2018, so perhaps that is where the discrepancy occurs and the charts from Google are showing the history of the primary exchange ticker (DYL)?

Comment: What is the name of this company?

Comment: Is this Deep Yellow Limited (ASX: DYL; OTC: DYLLF)?

Comment: @Flux see the update please; yes that is the ticker combo

Comment: Please take a screenshot of the Fidelity chart because an account is needed to see the chart.

Comment: @Flux updated with screenshot; Fidelity and OTCMarkets have near identical charts

Comment: "I'm looking at a company that is not available for US investors on the ASX" — Why is it not available for US investors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do OTC stocks trade similarly to their foreign exchange equivalents?

For [F shares](https://www.otcmarkets.com/files/FAQ-F-Shares.pdf) (such as DYLLF), the answer is "yes". For OTC stocks in general, the answer is "no".

I'm sure that the discrepancies are caused by faulty data. The faulty data is likely caused by Deep Yellow's 1-for-20 reverse stock split in March 2017:

- January 2017: [Notice of Extraordinary General Meeting](https://deepyellow.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Notice-of-Extraordinary-General-Meeting-Proxy-Form-.pdf) for approving the 1-for-20 share consolidation.
- February 2017: [Results of General Meeting](https://deepyellow.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Results-of-General-Meeting-.pdf). Result: share consolidation approved by shareholders.
- March 2017: Share consolidation takes place.

However, I do not have access to reliable financial data to tell you which charts are correct.

Comment: Oh interesting, something I hadn't learned about. Do you know a good resource that talks about the differ ticker suffixes on the OTC? Such as F vs Y vs OB, etc.

Comment: You can see the list of fifth character suffixes here: https://otce.finra.org/otce/fifth-char-identifier

Comment: Excellent, good to know F shares trade at the same rate as their primary exchange component; so in this case if DYL or DYLLF starts to rise/fall, the other should rise/fall at a commensurate rate. What is the proper term for "primary exchange component"? Is it "parent ticker"?

Comment: I would say that DYL is the *underlying security* of DYLLF. However, I'm not sure if that is the proper terminology.

Comment: So if the underlying goes up say 40% on their primary exchange, the F shares *should* trade commensurately? The primary exchange for say DYLLF closes before US OTC Markets open, so I am curious to know if thats a generalization or not.

Comment: "So if the underlying goes up say 40% on their primary exchange, the F shares should trade commensurately?" — Yes. OTC:DYLLF is ASX: DYL. They are the same shares. When you buy DYLLF, your broker holds DYL somewhere on your behalf.