# Purchasing international stock or OTC F share equivalent?

Tags: united-states, stocks, stock-exchanges, international, international-trading

I asked [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/139930/otc-stocks-and-their-foreign-stock-exchange-equivalent) question and got a great response by Flux, now I am faced with another dilemma:

> Purchase the OTC F share or the "original" on the respective exchange?

My broker is Fidelity, and through international trading I can purchase UEX via UEX:CA or UEXCF.

Is there any reason to favor purchasing an OTC F share over international trading or vice versa?

Comment: I think you should also ask Fidelity for their advice regarding this issue.

Comment: @Flux Yea I will. Best I can tell is that the fees may be lower; ~$25 for UEX:CA vs $50 for UEXCF because nothing is held at DTC.

Comment: Note that F shares of Canadian companies are often treated differently than other F shares. The transaction fees for Canadian F shares are usually lower than for other F shares.

Comment: @Flux I called Fidelity, and they said beyond fees it comes down to 2 things: liquidity and currency rates. If OTC is less liquid than the foreign exchange, could be tough to sell. If I purchase with USD and that's converted to say AUD and the exchange rate rises, I will lose money. So there is a matter of figuring out currency risk.